# eclipse line break figure

Tags: eclipse, line-breaks

I accidently set some setting in eclipse which shows some sign after every line. Could anyway tell me how to remove the same.

[image: line break sign]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are whitespace characters. Those characters represent formatting based tags such as line breaks, tabs, etc.

You can disable them by going to the Eclipse `Preferences`. They are under `General -> Editors -> Text Editors` and the option is `Show whitespace characters`. Just uncheck it and hit `OK` and that should take care of it.